# equivalent of vbCrLf in c#

Tags: c#, list, split, language-comparisons

I have a to do this:

```
AccountList.Split(vbCrLf)
```

In c# AccountList is a string.
How can i do?

thanks

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You are looking for [`System.Environment.NewLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx).

On Windows, this is equivalent to `\r\n` though it could be different under another .NET implementation, such as Mono on Linux, for example.

Comment: Theoretically bad answer.... this may change when run on Linux/Mono.... it is not "CRLF" but "the line separator defined on this computer type".

No risk on Windows.... but then... ;)

Comment: the solution is:
AccountList.Split(System.Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray())

Comment: I tried this: `string[] strOptions = txtOptions.Text.Split(System.Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray());` and if there are four options by pressing enter after each, it returns 7 instance instead of 4.

Comment: @TomTom is totally right. 'System.Environment.NewLine' should not be encouraged as a decent alternative to vbCrLf.

Answer (score 13):

I typically abbreviate so that I can use several places in my code.  Near the top, do something like this:

```
 string nl = System.Environment.NewLine;
```

Then I can just use "nl" instead of the full qualification everywhere when constructing strings.

Answer (score 10):

```
AccountList.Split("\r\n");
```

Answer (score 7):

Add a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic to your project.

Then insert the using statement

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
```

Use the defined constant vbCrLf:

```
private const string myString = "abc" + Constants.vbCrLf;
```

Comment: Might be better to use ControlChars.CrLf, as that also includes ControlChars.Cr and ControlChars.Lf as chars (not strings).

Comment: @jmoreno: The question was about `vbCrLf`. There is no need to use the ControlChars class. But the result is identical.

Comment: The result is identical, but it includes more options later.

Answer (score 6):

There is no equivalent of `vbCrLf` constant in C#. C#'s `System.Environment.NewLine` is an equivalent of `vbNewLine` in Visual Basic, it's NOT an equivalent of `vbCrLf`, because the value `System.Environment.NewLine` depends on OS where the C# application is running (and so does `vbNewLine`) - see [msdn link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.constants.vbnewline?view=net-5.0) as a reference.

In C# you can use `"\r\n"` instead of `vbCrLf`, as already was mentioned in one of the comments.

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking for

[System.Environment.NewLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

I think that "\r\n" should work fine

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
AccountList.Split(new String[]{"\r\n"},System.StringSplitOptions.None);
```

or

```
AccountList.Split(new String[]{"\r\n"},System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public  string VB2 = System.Environment.NewLine + System.Environment.NewLine;
public string VBCrLf = System.Environment.NewLine;

MessageBox.Show("Error: " + VB2 +  E.Message,"Error",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation );
```

Comment: please add some explanation

Answer (score -4):

```
"FirstLine" + "<br/>" "SecondLine"
```

Comment: This is not equivalent.

Comment: HTML newline, only useful when C# is outputting to a webpage.  Not useful in C# output to console or scripting, like in messagebox.